# How to delete label from if they are created in function?

Tags: python, tkinter, label, row-removal

I am doing app where I get different time zones by the input and then it is displayed on that window of mine, I can stack as many time zones as I would like in one window, however when I made this function I don't get any error messages, as well button CLEAR does not do anything.

The first function `result()` works great.

The function `clear_button()` does not do anything, I tried using global variables, and defining label outside of function and nothing worked.

I also tried using lambda within button widget itself, instead of passing a function to use destroy() method for result_label without success.

```
result_label = tk.Label(time_frame, text=world_times())

def result():
    global result_label
    result_label = tk.Label(time_frame, text=world_times())
    result_label.pack()


def clear_button():
    global result_label
    result_label = tk.Label(time_frame, text=world_times())
    result_label.destroy()


btn_accept = tk.Button(time_frame, text='Accept', command=result)
btn_accept.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor='ne')

btn_clear = tk.Button(time_frame, text='Clear', command=clear_button)
btn_clear.pack(side=RIGHT, anchor='ne')
```

Comment: remove `result_label = tk.Label(time_frame, text=world_times())` from `clear_button()`

Comment: Thank you! case solved, now have to figure out how to remove everything not only the last one

Comment: What everything?

Comment: Every time I would click on my accept button, It would keep giving new timezones, one after another below, then clicking clear button removes only last given result

Comment: the quickest way to destroy all the labels at once would be to place them in a frame and destroying the frame.